# Regex matching key val within object array

Tags: javascript, regex

Using https://regexr.com/ I've been trying to match pieces within a data object.

**json**

```
{"unit":{"id":1,"val":"px","name":"px"},"type":{"id":3,"val":"HORIZONTAL_BAR","name":"Horizontal Bar"},"zoom":{"id":2,"val":"DEFAULT","name":"Show"},"scale":{"id":2,"val":"TRUE","name":"Show"},"fullscreen":{"id":1,"val":"FALSE","name":"Hide"},"street":{"id":2,"val":"TRUE","name":"Show"},"poi":{"id":1,"val":"FALSE","name":"Disable"},"draggable":{"id":2,"val":"TRUE","name":"Enable"},"doubleclick":{"id":2,"val":"TRUE","name":"Enable"},"mouse":{"id":2,"val":"TRUE","name":"Enable"},"gesture":{"id":2,"val":"auto","name":"Auto"},"map":{"id":1,"val":"ROADMAP","name":"Road Map"},"mapid":"mapkit-9479","api":"","lat":"51.343695608206275","lng":"-2.4871419408111706","zoomlvl":13,"width":600,"height":400,"position":{},"route":{},"infowindow":{"enable":false,"title":false,"tel":false,"email":false,"web":false,"desc":false},"visible":1,"lon":"-2.4871419408111706","user_id":4575,"map_url":"26T9Te","snazzy":{"id":12,"snazzy_id":11,"name":"Blue","json":"[{\"featureType\":\"all\",\"stylers\":[{\"hue\":\"#0000b0\"},{\"invert_lightness\":"true"},{\"saturation\":-30}]}]"}}
```

This is an example of json and if you were to lint it, it would fail mainly due to this segment.

```
{\"invert_lightness\":"true"}
```

What I'm trying to do is by using REGEX is to match and replace to fix the issue

I've tried `\\"(.*)\\":"(.*)"` because I thought it would match any `"` that has no slash and I could replace it with a slash. so it would look like `{\"invert_lightness\":\"true\"}` and fix it.

But the regex query I wrote ends up with one match:

`\"featureType\":\"all\",\"stylers\":[{\"hue\":\"#0000b0\"},{\"invert_lightness\":"true"},{\"saturation\":-30}]}]"`

Comment: @wp78de: the problem here is that the JSON isn't well formatted and the asker is trying to repair it before using a JSON Parser.

Comment: Change the first `.*` with `[^"]*` and use a non-greedy quantifier: `.*?` for the second.

Comment: Casimir et Hippolyte could you add that as an answer and explain what `[^"]*` does?

Comment: Wherever that json comes from, the property “json” has been encoded twice.  A better idea would be to fix the double encoding at the source, rather than trying to pull it apart with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you could use

```
\\"(.*?)\\"
```

and replace this with

```
"$1"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lQ2sNS/1/).

---

This says:

```
\\"   # match one backslash and "
(.*?) # capture 0+ characters in between, lazily into group 1
\\"   # same as above
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/"\[/g, '[').replace(/\]"/, ']')
```

Comment: I see your idea. Are you sure that all double quotes have to be escaped in your pattern (look carefully at the string)?

Comment: yes, it was wrong, I've edited it now, should work now :) But I guess that your searching more for an unique regexp for three errors